# copy of Only Root elements with attributes , using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Input:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <root attribute1="attribute1" attribute2="attribute2" attribute3="attribute3">
        <child1>
            <grandchild1>xxx1</<grandchild1>
            <grandchild2>xxx2</<grandchild2>        
        </child1>
        .   
        <child1000>
        </child1000>
    </root>
```

Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root attribute1="attribute1" attribute2="attribute2" attribute3="attribute3">

</root>
```

I only want the root element with all attributes. *** provided number of attributes on root node not fixed.

Comment: Well, `xsl:template match="/*"` matches the root element, `xsl:copy` will copy it and `xsl:copy-of select="@*"` copies the attributes.

Comment: Problem is, it wont copy the end root element tag . This is what I tried       <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: Well, http://xsltransform.net/gWEamL4 does the job fine as far as I can tell, unless you expect the markup of the input to be preserved, which XSLT never does as it works on a tree of nodes and serialized them at the end. So what is the problem in your view, that the result used the form `<root attribute1="attribute1" attribute2="attribute2" attribute3="attribute3"/>` instead of `<root attribute1="attribute1" attribute2="attribute2" attribute3="attribute3"></root>`? Please edit your question and show us exactly which result you get and which you want.